# If $T: V \to W$ is a vs isomorphism and $T^{-1}(W_i)=V_i, \,\, i \in \{1,2 \}$. Then $v \in V_1 \cap V_2 \implies T(v) \in W_1 \cap W_2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm following a proof in my book on representation theory and one of the steps in the proof is something along the lines of:

If $T: V \to W$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces and $T^{-1}(W_i)=V_i, \,\, i \in \{1,2 \}$. Then $v \in V_1 \cap V_2 \Rightarrow T(v) \in W_1 \cap W_2$.

I tried following the steps: $v \in V_1 \cap V_2 \Rightarrow T(v) \in T(V_1 \cap V_2) = T(T^{-1}(W_1) \cap T^{-1}(W_2))$, which seems close to $W_1 \cap W_2$ but I'm hesitant to "distribute" the $T$ through $\cap$ to obtain $TT^{-1}(W_1) \cap TT^{-1}(W_2)$ because I'm not sure why (or if) this is valid. I feel silly for not knowing why this works.

Comment: You are thinking very hard. If $v\in V_1\cap V_2$, then $v\in V_1$, so $T(v)\in W_1$ by definition of $V_1$. Similarly $T(v)\in W_2$ so $T(v)\in W_1\cap W_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

$v\in V_{1}\cap V_{2}\implies v\in T^{-1}(W_{1})\cap T^{-1}(W_{2})$. Thus, $T(v)\in W_{1}\cap W_{2}$. This follows since $v\in T^{-1}(W)\iff T(v)\in W$.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is indeed valid in this case, because $T$ is injective.

You need to check that
$$TT^{-1}(W_1) \cap TT^{-1}(W_2)\subset T(T^{-1}(W_1) \cap T^{-1}(W_2));$$
(the other inclusion is pretty easy). So take $w\in TT^{-1}(W_1) \cap TT^{-1}(W_2)$; then $w=T(v_1)=T(v_2)$, with $v_1\in T^{-1}(W_1)$ and $v_2\in T^{-1}(W_2)$. Then because $T$ is injective, $v_1=v_2\in T^{-1}(W_1) \cap T^{-1}(W_2)$ and this means
$$w=T(v_1)\in T(T^{-1}(W_1) \cap T^{-1}(W_2)).$$
Incidentally none of this requires $T$ to be linear or even $V$ and $W$ to be vector spaces, it is also true for functions between sets.